# Which filter should I use? Just want to keep high count values

Tags: filter, signal-processing

I am asking this question because I am not quite sure which filter I should be using.

Mine is simply a signal made up of discrete values as such `s = [1 2 2 2 3 4 2 4 3 4 5 3 2 3 3]`. Then I would like, per window size, a filtered signal. So e.g. if I use a window size of 5 for `s` then I would get; `s_filtered = [2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3]`. **Hence, I want to keep the values that statistically occur most often per window size.**

Currently I am using just a median filter, but I do no think this is the correct approach.

Here is some python code to demonstrate what I am doing (but as said, which I think is wrong).

```
import numpy as np
import pylab *
from scipy.signal import medfilt

test = np.random.randint(10, size=1000)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,sharey=True, sharex=True, figsize=(15,5))
ax1.plot(test)
ax1.plot(medfilt(test,[99]),'r')
plt.show()
```

[image: Random data with median filtered signal in red.]

Where the red line is the filtered signal for a window size of 99.

Comment: Not clear what you want, you use median filter whic is kind of low pass filter, and you wish to have high pass filter?

Comment: Question is unclear. If you just want to keep high frequencies, use a high pass filter. Or, by "high frequency values" do you mean the values that statistically occur most often?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, I would like to keep the values that statistically occur most often per window size. Will edit question now.

Comment: Median filter can introduce errors. Sounds like you want to count occurrences of each value, sort these counts, eliminate the rarest, then ... what do you replace the rarest with, or can you just delete them giving a shorter window? Not enough context to tell that, I think.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I see, I really want to keep the value of highest count and place that value in place of the others in the a new, filtered, signal.

Comment: So with the same sliding window, instead of the median value, you want to replace the input value with the most common value ... you could call this a "mode filter". Looks simple enough.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I see, a mode filter. Will check that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, you are correct that a median filter won't fulfil them.

Consider the following sequence of values (sorted as per the median filter algorithm with a window of length 9.

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6 6 6 9)
```

The median value is 5 but the highest frequency value (statistically) is 6.

Now if you did a population count

```
Bin    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Count  - 1 1 1 1 1 3 - - 1
```

you can identify the highest frequency value as 6. I don't know if this approach has a formal name, but "mode filter" seems to describe it well, by analogy with "median filter".

This could get computationally expensive.

However if you used a sliding window (say, length 9) then as each new value enters the window, you increment its count, and as it leaves the window you decrement its count, then maintaining the population counts is cheap. In other words, before calculating sample N, you add sample (N+4) and remove sample (N-4) from the popcount bins.

Then you loop over the bins to find the bin with the maximum count.

How you resolve cases where two or more bins have the same max count, e.g. in the sequence

```
(1 2 3 3 5 6 6 8 9)
```

giving counts

```
Bin    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Count  - 1 1 2 - 1 2 - 1 1
```

where you could take the answer as either 3 or 6 ... that's up to you.